# Unable to download skobbler map for offline use - Android

Tags: android, offline, skmaps

This is the code I am using,

```
 int version=2;
 public void downloadMapsXMLForVersion(int version) {
        String url = SKPackageManager.getInstance().getMapsXMLPathForVersion(version);
   System.out.println(url);
         }
```

I have mentioned the correct key that I got from developer account during intialization.

The URL returned by it says

> `NoSuchKey`The specified key does not
>   exist.ngxmaps/versioned/full/v1/2/Maps.xmlBD6ED7C69819E911Ys14Q61AkJlyrWOsl+XW+DfFG+j6KCayLTb75s9hF3TizKf8mI7AlIWW8o1OL5Kbo/bDd/MeQv4=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check that the SDK is online - `initMapSettings.setConnectivityMode(SKMaps.CONNECTIVITY_ONLINE);` - as the otherwise the xml download will fail.

Then implement `SKMapUpdateListener` and check if `onMapVersionSet` is called - this means that the map version was read and now the download should work.